# Facets of polytopes and toric morphisms

Tags: toric-varieties, lattice-polytopes

To every convex lattice polytope $P$ is associated a toric variety $X_P$, which can be realized as a projective variety.

Consider a facet $f$ of $P$, i.e. a codimension one boundary of the polytope.

1. What is the relation between $X_P$ and $X_f$?
2. More concretely, are there natural morphisms $\phi : X_P \to X_f$ and what are their descriptions in various coordinates? (affine and projective).